# <i class="icon icon-Speach-BubbleDialog"></i> doesn't work

Tags: html, font-awesome

I've used a free html template to create a landing page and i've seen some website user the font-awsome library to work with icons like this:

I've followed instructions here: http://fontawesome.io/3.2.1/get-started/

but when I write the code in my index.html the icon doesn't show

```
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="feature boxed feature-1 text-center">
                                <i class="icon icon-Speach-BubbleDialog"></i>
                                <h5>Chat With Friends</h5>
                                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="feature boxed feature-1 text-center">
                                <i class="icon icon-Photos"></i>
                                <h5>Share Moments</h5>
                                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="feature boxed feature-1 text-center">
                                <i class="icon icon-Pizza-Slice"></i>
                                <h5>Organize Events</h5>
                                <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--end of row-->
                </div>
```

any Ideas?

Comment: you can use link http://fontawesome.io/icons/

Comment: it can use fa class such as <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>

Comment: *Heads up! These docs are for v3.2.1, which is no longer officially supported.* upgrade to newer version of FontAwesome.

Comment: use <i class="icon icon-comment"></i>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Please check this

Comment: where can I see the entire list of options? and how can I take control of the size?

Comment: You can search here for icons
http://fontawesome.io/icons/ . Also use font-size for size control.